# CSS Getting footer same position as content

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my website I am trying to position my footer in the centre of the screen. I have tried using `text-align: center;` for my footer but it did not work as it should I want the footer to be in the middle of the screen. Where the text says "Skriven i HTML".

[image]

I want to position the footer to the centre.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #F16529;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 16px;
  }
  div.item {
    width: initial;
    max-width: 256px;
  }
}

div.item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 256px;
}

.blog {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

img.wrap {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 30px 0px;
}

img.align-right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

div.article-container {
  padding: 5px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  text-align: center;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  img.align-right {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
  }
  div.article-container {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 256px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Inlämningsuppgift 6</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!--nav bar-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li style="list-style: none"><br></li>
      <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
      <li>
        <h2>Menu</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="active" href="#lank">Länk 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#lank2">Länk 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#lank3">Länk 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#lank4">Länk 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--navbar end-->
  <!--container for blog posts 3 images-->
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Innehåll</h1>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end-->
  <hr>
  <!--container for article -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="article-container clearfix">
      <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end-->
  <footer>
    Skriven i HTML 5.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your footer stretches the whole screen, try removing the width of the left column from it:  `footer { left:25%; }` - you may need to add 16px padding too to make it line up with the other containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. `footer` is in center of the `body`. If you want it to be in center of the container, you need to move your footer in `.container` div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="article-container clearfix">
    <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi t.......</p>
   </div>
   <footer>
      Skriven i HTML 5.
   </footer>
</div><!--end-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, since your footer element in the body tag.

Since in the CSS you only use `container` as selector, add a class attribute `contailer` for footer. Then all the CSS(alignment) used for container will be apply to the `footer` also.

```
<footer class="container">
        Skriven i HTML 5.
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possible solutions. Even now footer content is at center. You can see that if you use debugg ing tools.

What you can do is first move footer inside container so your HTML looks like this:

```
<!--nav bar-->
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li style="list-style: none"><br></li>
        <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
        <li>
            <h2>Menu</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="active" href="#lank">Länk 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#lank2">Länk 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#lank3">Länk 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#lank4">Länk 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav><!--navbar end-->
<!--container for blog posts 3 images-->
<div class="container">
    <h1>Innehåll</h1>
    <div class="item">
        <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
    </div>
</div><!--end-->
<hr>
<!--container for article -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="article-container clearfix">
        <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
<footer>
    Skriven i HTML 5.
</footer>
</div><!--end-->
```

And then footer content would be at center but you will notice margin on left and right side of it. If you want to remove that you can do this. In css add:

```
footer {
 margin:0 -16px;
}
```

Where -16px on margin is amount of padding on container element.

Also you can try to add container class to footer, it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the footer inside the last div ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awt09gza/#&togetherjs=ctuqSiIR4C)).

Or, I would use this instead of the footer :

```
 <div style="position:relative;"> 
      <div style="position:absolute; margin:0 auto; padding:1rem;">
           Footer content
      </div>
 </div>
```